# Access NATed remote system through an existing ssh connection

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh, tunneling

There is a machine RemoteA that is behind a NAT somewhere on the internet. It can connect to an ssh server.

There is another machine called RemoteB that also has a connection to the same ssh server.

If RemoteA connects to the SSH Server via an ssh connection, and RemoteB is also connected to an ssh server, can RemoteB tunnel all the way to RemoteA over the existing connection through the SSHServer?

The goal is for RemoteB to connect to RemoteA but it can't because of a NAT. But if both RemoteA and RemoteB can connect over ssh to SSHServer, it seems like a tunnel should be possible?

Comment: Clarification: RemoteB wants to SSH to remoteA. SSH server does not have a route to RemoteA until RemoteA sshes to it.

Answer (score 0):

Two-way tunnel solves this:

RemoteA is sshed in using

```
ssh -N -R 8822:localhost:22 user@SSHServer
```

RemoteB sshes into SSHServer and then uses:

```
ssh -p 8822 user@localhost
```

And that point RemoteB is in RemoteA.